# set width of inner div on scrollable element to 100% of scrollable width

Tags: html, css

How do I get the width of this inner content div to be equal to the width of the scrollable area?

```
<div class="scrollable">
    <div class="content">short</div>
    <div class="content">very looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text</div>
</div>
```

with CSS:

```
.scrollable {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.content {
    background-color: lightblue;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XBVsR/12/

**PROBLEM:** if you scroll across you can see that the background does not go all the way across as it should.

I've tried setting width: 100%, overflow: visible, etc, to no avail.

**EDIT:** I've updated to make clear that I don't want the text to wrap - I want the horizontal scroll on the whole thing.

Comment: Do u need to set the background for each text individually? Wouldn't it be easier to just set the scrollable background?

Comment: @Ms.Nobody, yeah i need to set them individually because they are actually part of a scrollable menu with background and border, this is just a simple example to isolate the issue.

Comment: So you want to have menu that will have to be scrolled? Can you put somewhere the whole thing? Or just the menu but with real items because I don't understand why u want menu to be scrollable vertically :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `display: table-row;` for nested divs. Look at [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/XBVsR/5/)

Comment: Simple and elegant, that's great !

Comment: Perfecto! Cheers dude! Any ideas why display: block; didn't work whereas display: table-row does?

Comment: I don't know how the browsers render engine suppose to work. But I guess that when overflowing occurs, browser does not take into consideration the width of nested **block** on which the background will be rendered. In case of using `table-row` width would be calculated with consider of contained text width.

Comment: :/ I'm running into a situation where this is happening with flex box, so I already have `display: flex`. Going to have to come up with some hacky solution then I guess.

Comment: With `display: table-row` if inner DIV is too small, it is not stretched to the full width of the outer DIV. So this answer is not really solves "set width of inner div on scrollable element to 100% of scrollable width" problem. It also doesn't allow to set `padding`. http://jsfiddle.net/8rsptwxu/

Answer (score 0):

Add to .content class

```
overflow: auto;
```

Updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/XBVsR/11/

Do remember that this would affect all elements with class .content. You might wanna give it another class name too.

Comment: i think he wants the scroll

Comment: @MadanlalArora that's correct, I need it to scroll.  I actually also have white-space: nowrap to ensure it scrolls.

Comment: @MadanlalArora "width of this inner content div to be equal to the width of the scrollable area", the scrollable being the parent class. So, I believe the objective is to have the width equal.

Comment: dude check the fiddle i gave in my ans does that solve your issue ?

Comment: @Jaay In that case you need to add overflow: auto to the child element. Check the update.

Comment: @MadanlalArora Yes, I believe so.

Answer (score 0):

just give this to your content

```
 overflow: auto;
```

Comment: this just scrolls the individual content element, but i need the whole thing to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You can't if you're going to set the outer div to be width 300px.  It's the unbroken text breaking the bounding box.  You can, however, wrap the word by adding this to the content CSS:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

However, if that 300px doesn't matter to you, you can move the overflow: auto from the scrollable class to the content one, and that, too, should fix the background issue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use two nested inner `div`s instead of one inner `div`.

The outer nested `div` should have `display: table` and also should have `min-width: 100%;` and `min-height: 100%;`, while the innermost nested `div` should have `display: table-cell`.

This way the table will stretch in both ways (horizontally and vertically) to the outer scrollable container's viewport if the contents of the table cell is too small, but will stretch futher if the content is big enough.

It also allows to set `padding`s on innermost div.

```css
.outer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.middle {
  background: lightpink;
  display: table;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.inner {
  display: table-cell;
  white-space: pre-line;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="inner">loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong
and another one text
and another one text
and another one text
and another one text
and another one text
and another one text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="outer">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="inner">short
    short
    short
    short
    short
    short
    short
    short
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="outer">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="inner">short</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4cuzqo06/