# How to set width of a DIV to 100% if it is in a scrollable parent DIV?

Tags: html, css

Would like to set the width of `child_sub` DIV 100% width so that even if I scroll the parent DIV horizontally, the `child_sub` DIV should cover the parent DIV's whole width.

**Here's the code:**

```css
.main {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}
.main_sub {
  width:100%;
}
.main_sub_sub {
  display:inline-block;
  width:50px;
}
.child_sub {
  width:100%;
  background:darkred;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="main_sub">
    <p class="main_sub_sub">1</p>
    <p class="main_sub_sub">2</p>
    <p class="main_sub_sub">3</p>
    <p class="main_sub_sub">4</p>
    <p class="main_sub_sub">5</p>
    <p class="main_sub_sub">6</p>
    <p class="main_sub_sub">7</p>
    <p class="main_sub_sub">8</p>
    <p class="main_sub_sub">9</p>
    <p class="main_sub_sub">10</p>
    <p class="main_sub_sub">11</p>
    <p class="main_sub_sub">12</p>
    <p class="main_sub_sub">13</p>
    <p class="main_sub_sub">14</p>
    <p class="main_sub_sub">15</p>
    <p class="main_sub_sub">16</p>
    <p class="main_sub_sub">17</p>
    <p class="main_sub_sub">18</p>
    <p class="main_sub_sub">19</p>
    <p class="main_sub_sub">20</p>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="child_sub">
    <div>
    some
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hf8sgykd/1/) to play around

As you can see in the fiddle, if I scroll the parent `main` DIV  the `child_sub` DIV which is set at **100%** only covers till `10th` field in the `main` DIV. I m trying to default set the `child_sub` DIV to cover the full length of `main` DIV.

I have come across the SO answer regarding the same query which told me to add `display:table-row` to the `child_sub`, But unfortunately, I couldn't make it work by myself.

[SO Query over the same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17406175/16356706)

Any Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: _"the child_sub DIV should cover the parent DIV's whole width."_ - that's what it already _does_. Your `.main` element did _not_ get wider, just because the content _inside_ it is allowed to overflow.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @CBroe.
I was confused about what exactly your required output is. or whether you're expecting all the elements in that particular `DIV` to be adjusted in the 100% width no scroll and overflow ??

Answer (score 1):

Right below your `.main` set a container with `display:grid;`.

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="main_sub"></div>
    <div class="child_sub"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This way it will take the whole width.

```css
.grid{
  display:grid;
}
.grid hr {
  width: 100%;
}
```

### DEMO:

```css
.main {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}
.grid{
  display:grid;
}
.grid hr {
  width: 100%;
}
.main_sub {
  width:100%;
}
.main_sub_sub {
  display:inline-block;
  width:50px;
}
.child_sub {
  width:100%;
  background:darkred;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="main_sub">
      <p class="main_sub_sub">1</p>
      <p class="main_sub_sub">2</p>
      <p class="main_sub_sub">3</p>
      <p class="main_sub_sub">4</p>
      <p class="main_sub_sub">5</p>
      <p class="main_sub_sub">6</p>
      <p class="main_sub_sub">7</p>
      <p class="main_sub_sub">8</p>
      <p class="main_sub_sub">9</p>
      <p class="main_sub_sub">10</p>
      <p class="main_sub_sub">11</p>
      <p class="main_sub_sub">12</p>
      <p class="main_sub_sub">13</p>
      <p class="main_sub_sub">14</p>
      <p class="main_sub_sub">15</p>
      <p class="main_sub_sub">16</p>
      <p class="main_sub_sub">17</p>
      <p class="main_sub_sub">18</p>
      <p class="main_sub_sub">19</p>
      <p class="main_sub_sub">20</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="child_sub">
      <div>
      some
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.child_sub` already has 100% width of the parent, overflow does not change dimensions of a div.

There are multiple ways to achieve the same result,
The easiest being to remove the `.child_sub` from within the scroll

Another method is to add `position: absolute` to `.child_sub`